# how to download war files from wildfly 8

Tags: jboss, wildfly-8

Wildfly 8:

1. Where are the deployed war files located on the server file system?
2. How do I download them? I tried using the JBoss CLI as well as the Web Interface.

Answer (score 5):

Found the war files to be located here. In this directory I found several subdirectories. The war files were all named content and did not have an extension. I could figure out what they were based on file size and timestamp.

```
wildfly location\standalone\data\content
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the files 'after' they have been deployed? This generally isn't a good idea as it isn't guaranteed to be exactly the same as the source archive.

The standard location for the deployment archives is ./standalone/deployments/ although this can be changed in the configuration.

After an archive is deployed you can see the exact location of there the deployed archive came from in the configuration, it will be written to the bottom of the xml file.

Comment: Is it ok to use the deployed war file as a backup in case a newly deployed war fails?

Answer (score 0):

There is a download button to download the .war
in the management console localhost:9990
click the view button near your war
on top you will find a download icon

Answer (score 0):

Access Management Console -> Deployments -> beside your target war file , click 'View' -> Select the war file -> click download icon beside the search bar

Answer (score -1):

I found it in the `%WILDFLY_HOME%\standalone\temp\`  directory. If it is not present there then you can perform a search in all the subdirectories of the wildfly.